# Master detail ViewController when detailViewController is dynamic

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, storyboard

I'm building an app for iPhone, I want to use storyboard in XCode to do a simple selection from a tableView (let's call it master table view controller with couple rows) then through navigation it goes to next page and shows a detail view for that selection.
I have in my code a base class representing my detailViewController, and have 2-3 driver classes of this base class representing what I want to show in detail view controller in second page, can someone give me an idea how to set destination viewController (detailViewController) dynamically to one of my child class based on the selected row in master view controller using storyboard?

Usually you assign a class to destination class in storyboard for your detail view controller with using segue, but since my destination class could be a different (child class) how you set this in storyboard?

Thank you,
Kam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways that you could go about this:

**Storyboard Method**

- Use storyboards to build relationships between your master table view
  controller and the detail view controllers.  In the storyboard, you
  can totally have more than one segue going from the
  MasterTableViewController to various other View Controllers.

  `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detail view identifier" sender:self];

  }
- Be sure to name your segues inside your storyboard.

**Code Method**

1. Inside your MasterTableViewController:

   `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   MyViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view controller identifier"]];

   [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion^{}];

   }

Answer (score 0):

As you say, instead of wiring the segue directly to the cell in the story board, you can instead handle the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and instantiate whatever view controller (or subclass thereof) you want from there.

To manually load a storyboard based VC, make sure you still give the VC an identifier in the storyboard in interface builder and then do something like this to load it:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = self.storyboard;

DetailViewController* detailVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@ "DetailViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

If you truly want a different VC layout, for your different sub-classes, you may want to have different VCs in the storyboard.  Or set an initializer that lets you set it up how you need it.